# Select rows from dataframe based on substring A or B in a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, substring

Sorry, I needed to edit my question as I'm actually looking for substrings with more than one character. The suggested answers are good, but mostly work for one character strings.

```
import panda as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'ju1 j4 abjul boy noc s1 asep'.split(),
                 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
print(test)


       A  B
0    ju1  1
1     j4  2
2  abjul  3
3    boy  4
4    noc  5
5     s1  6
6   asep  7
```

I know I can select all the rows that contain 'ju' with

```
subset = test[test['A'].str.contains('ju')]
print(subset)

       A  B
0    ju1  1
1  abjul  3
```

Is there an elegant way to select all rows that contain either 'ju' or 'as'?

This works as suggested below, are there other ways that also work?

```
ju = test.A.str.contains('ju')
as = test.A.str.contains('as')
subset = test[ju | as]
```

Comment: `test[test['A'].str.contains('[js]+')]`

Comment: test[(test['A'].str.contains('j')) | (test[test['A'].str.contains('s')])]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***option 1***
try using `str.match`

```
test[test.A.str.match('.*[js].*')]
```

***option 2***
`set` operations

```
s = test.A.apply(set)
test[s.sub(set(list('js'))).lt(s)]
```

***option 3***
`set` operations with `numpy` broadcasting

```
s = test.A.apply(set)
test[(~(np.array([[set(['j'])], [set(['s'])]]) - s.values).astype(bool)).any(0)]
```

***option 4***
separate conditions

```
cond_j = test.A.str.contains('j')
cond_s = test.A.str.contains('s')
test[cond_j | cond_s]
```

---

All yield

```
       A  B
0     j1  1
1     j4  2
2  abjul  3
5     s1  6
6   asep  7
```

---

***time testing***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
In [13]: test.loc[test.A.str.contains(r'[js]')]
Out[13]:
       A  B
0     j1  1
1     j4  2
2  abjul  3
5     s1  6
6   asep  7
```